# Unity: Set new Origin using empty GameObject

Tags: unity, 3d, pivot

You used to be able to set a GameObject with your Mesh as a child of an Empty GameObject. By rotating the Empty the Mesh would rotate around the position of the Empty. Now after the update it seems it's auto calculating a Median Point.

Here's the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxB_6c75oP0

I should be able to keep the original Origin of the empty GameObject no matter what children it gets. What happened to Unity?

This is how it used to be: https://answers.unity.com/questions/609267/how-to-change-the-origin-of-a-gameobject.html

Comment: If you look at the button next to the `RectTransform` tool, what does it say? "Pivot" or "Center"?

Comment: Specifically, I think Hellium is asking about the [Transform Gizmo Toggles](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/Editor-GizmoButtons.png) mentioned in the [docs about the editor Toolbar](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Toolbar.html).

Comment: I agree with Hellium and DM Gregory. It looks like you've switched the Gizmo rotation mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next to the `RectTransform` tool, you will find a toggle that has two states "Pivot" or "Center".

[image]

This **Gizmo handle position toggle** is used to define the location of the Transform tool Gizmo of the selected objets, and the handles use to manipulate the Gizmo itself.

- When set to **Pivot**, the Gizmo is positionned at the actual pivot point of a Mesh.
- When set to **Center**, the Gizmo is positionned at the center of the GameObject’s rendered bounds.

According to your problem, the toggle is set to **Center**. Click on the toggle to set it to **Pivot**. Now, you have the correct pivot point of your empty.

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html